# Oozie: What does Next Materialization in Oozie Indicates

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have scheduled an oozie workflow with CRON frequency as `1,2,4 * * * *`. My job is scheduled for 11:31, 11:32 and 11:34.

However, "Next Materialization" is given as `Tue, 22 Aug 2017 12:31:00 IST`.
I haven't mentioned any recurring time. So just wanted to know why the Next Materialization time is 12:31.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier to reason in UTC, and not mix in your local time zone (which you mention only incidentally, as if the whole planet used India time...)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Its about the time interval and not the timezone. Though the whole planet do not use India  time, but everywhere 1 hour is equivalent to 1 hour only.